# Load external content into div and open accordion

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to understand how to load external content into a `div` and then open an accordion and navigate to the content within it.

I'm using the following jQuery on a click event to load html content into a `div` with id="acd":

```
$("#customers").click( function () {
        $('#acd').load('includes/customers.html');
});
```

Within customers.html are two accordions where the first accordion (collapseOne) is collapsed as defined by `collapse` and the second (collapseTwo) is expanded as defined by `collapse in`. Here is the basic structure:

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
 <div>
    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
    Accordion One
    </a>
 </div>
 <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel">
  <div>
    <p>Accordion One Content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
  Accordion Two
  </a>
 </div>
 <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel">
  <div>
    <p>Accordion Two Content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

With basic skills I've tried to modify the javascript so that it both loads the external content to #collapseOne and opens the accordion, but it remains collapsed. I assume that customers.html needs to have loaded completely before the accordion can be expanded, but unsure of how to handle that.

```
$('#customers').click(function() {
  $('#acd').load('includes/customers.html#collapseOne').collapse("show");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure if this is what you're looking for.

Below is my example.

HTML

```
Just assume that the textarea below is external page
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4"><textarea class="form-control text t1">This is 1st html result</textarea></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><textarea class="form-control text t2">This is 2nd html result</textarea></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><textarea class="form-control text t3">This is 3rd html result</textarea></div>
</div>
<br/>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning test">
Click Me!
</button> 
@ Change and trigger click : 
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary bt" data-page="t1"  data-target="collapseOne">
Item #1
</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary bt" data-page="t2"  data-target="collapseTwo">
Item #2
</button> 
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary bt" data-page="t3"  data-target="collapseThree">
Item #3
</button> 
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.test').on('click',function(){

    var t1 = $(".t1").val(); // page 1
    var t2 = $(".t2").val(); // page 2
    var t3 = $(".t3").val(); // page 3

  /*
    change the html function to load @ ajax request 
  */

  $("#collapseOne > div").html(t1); 
  $("#collapseTwo > div").html(t2); 
  $("#collapseThree > div").html(t3); 

});

$('.bt').on('click',function(){

  var dt = $(this).data("target");
  var pg = $(this).data("page");
  // var rs = $("." + pg).prop("value"); @ 
  var rs = $("." + pg).val();

  /*
    change the html function to load @ ajax request 
    if you're using another version of bootstrap, please change 'active' to 'in'
  */

  $("#accordion").find("div.active").removeClass("active");
  $("#" + dt).addClass("active"); 
  $("#" + dt + " > div").html(rs); 

});
```

And working live example : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/2ba5k6j3/

I hope this example can help you.

Comment: Thanks synz, but this is a little different to what I'm looking for. This switches the content within each accordion with external content. In my scenario, clicking a link first changes the content on the page to html containing accordions, then I need it to open the first accordion.